# View utf-8 tuple element as string in python

Tags: python-2.7, tuples, utf8-decode

I have a list with Unicode utf-8 tuples like:

> ((u'\u0d2a\u0d31\u0d1e\u0d4d\u0d1e\u0d41',
>   u'\u0d15\u0d47\u0d3e\u0d23\u0d4d\u200d\u0d17\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d38\u0d4d'),
>   7.5860818562067314)

I want to convert the utf-8 code as string. I have tried decode. But getting error.
Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.encode('utf-8')` method instead of `.decode()`, because strings are represented in unicode type, and we want to get byte strings.

Here is great how-to about string encoding in python 2.7, must read it:
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

For example, `data[0][0].encode('utf-8')` produces normal result.

Comment: Please format your code in your answer properly. Otherwise, good answer

Answer (score 0):

Those are not UTF-8.

```
print data[0][0], data[0][1]
```